# Writing multichannel audio for MATLAB with libsndfile

Tags: c, matlab, libsndfile

I am trying to use libsndfile to write a multichannel wav that can be read by MATLAB 2010+.

the following code writes a 4 channel interleaved wav. all samples on channel 1 should be 0.1, on channel 2 they are 0.2, on channel 3 ... etc.

Each channel is 44100 samples in length.

I drag the wave file onto the MATLAB workspace and unfortunately MATLAB keeps returning "File contains uninterpretable data".

It may also be worth noting that when all samples are set to 0.0, MATLAB successfully reads the file, although very slowly.

I have successfully used libsndfile to read multichannel data written by MATLAB's wavwrite.m, so the library is setup up correctly I believe.

Audacity can read the resulting file from the code below.

VS 2012 64 bit compiler,
Win7 64bit, MATLAB 2015a

ref: the code has been adapted from http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/wavFiles.html

Any suggestions, I presume i'm making a simple error here?

Thanks

```
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
// Create interleaved audio data
int numFrames_out = 44100;
int channels = 4;
float *int_y;   
int_y = (float*)malloc(channels*numFrames_out*sizeof(float));   
long q=0;
for (long i = 0; i<numFrames_out; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<channels; j++)
    {
        int_y[q+j] = ((float)(j+1))/10.0;
    }
    q+=channels;
}


// Set multichannel file settings
SF_INFO info;
info.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_32;
info.channels = channels;
info.samplerate = 44100;

// Open sound file for writing
char out_filename[] = "out_audio.wav";
SNDFILE *sndFile = sf_open(out_filename, SFM_WRITE, &info);
if (sndFile == NULL) 
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening sound file '%s': %s\n", out_filename, sf_strerror(sndFile));
  return -1;
}

// Write frames
long writtenFrames = sf_writef_float(sndFile, int_y, numFrames_out);

// Check correct number of frames saved
if (writtenFrames != numFrames_out) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Did not write enough frames for source\n");
    sf_close(sndFile);
    free(int_y);
    return -1;
}
sf_close (sndFile);
}
```

Comment: I found a temporary work around - Audacity can read the wav file created using the code above, and so if I enable the export to multchannel wav feature of Audacity and then import that file into MATLAB, it works. This also confirms that MATLAB can read multichannel wav's (if it was in doubt) and the issue is somehow related to formatting.

Comment: I wish I new why someone -1 without explanation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only closing the output file (using sf_close()) in the error case. The output file will not be a well formed WAV file *unless* you call sf_close() at the end of your program.

Comment: Unfortunately the missing sf_close() from the demo code was not the issue. Matlab still reports the error whereas audacity works fine.

Comment: What does the `sndfile-info program` say about the file? That program is part of the libsndfile source distribution and is in a package called something like `sndfile-programs` in most linux distros.